# LINQ to Entities - How to retrieve a data and use it as a variable in the whole project

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 1 WinForm and 2 tables:

- Form1  contains   TextBox1
- Employee  contains     ID, LastName, FirstName, BirthDate.
- Tasks  contains   ID, TaskName

I need to input LastName and FirtName in TextBox1 to retrieve the related "TaskName" if exists,
then make the retrieved data usable from any location in the project

I need to know where to put the TaskName variable?
and how can I modify the next code to reach that purpose?

```
using (LINQtoEntitiesEntities MyEntities = new LINQtoEntitiesEntities())
{
ObjectQuery<Employee> Employee = MyEntities.Employee;
var query = (from p in Employee
where p.FirstName == TextBox1.Text.Trim()
select p.LasttName, p.FirstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If LastName and FirstName are being input (in that order) to TextBox1 then, assuming they are separated by a space or spaces, you can split them up as follows:

```
string[] items = TextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string lastName = items[0];
string firstName = items[1];
```

The second argument to the Split method deals with the possibility that there might be multiple spaces separating the last and first names.

If the ID column is used to link the Employee and Tasks tables, you should then be able to retrieve the related TaskName and place it in a global variable as follows:

// create a class to contain global variables if you don't already have one

```
static class Global
{
    public static string Task {get; set;}
}
```

// within some method in some other class

// insert above code to get last and first names

```
using (LINQtoEntitiesEntities MyEntities = new LINQtoEntitiesEntities())
{
   ObjectQuery<Employee> Employee = MyEntities.Employee;
   ObjectQuery<Tasks> Tasks = MyEntities.Tasks;
   Global.Task = (from e in Employee where e.LastName == lastName && e.FirstName == firstName join t in Tasks on e.ID equals t.ID select t.TaskName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

// retrieve global variable from elsewhere:

```
if (Global.Task != null)
{
   // do something with Global.Task
}
```

Comment: I would add some info about the danger of having global data and why we want to avoid that.